# can any one help me what would i do here?

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables. My table structure is like this:

```
Table 'customer' 
( 
    cust_id (PK), 
    cust_name, 
    cust_balance 
); 
and Table 'account' 
( 
    acc_id (PK), 
    cust_id(FK) --relating to customer table  
);
```

customer data:

```
name  cust_id
scott c100 
ford  c200
```

account data:

```
scott personal a100 
scott joint    a300
ford  personal a200
ford  joint    a300
```

Then what will be the value in account table's cust_id column?? If I am entering Scott's id then while querying it will show that only Scott has 2 accounts but that's not true, Ford also has 2 accounts. So how do I do this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to get a count of accounts per customer? You say you "enter" Scott's id and get back Scott's two accounts, would this not be the desired result when querying accounts by Scott's id?

Answer (score 0):

You could give the account table a dual PK, acc_id and cust_id, so when you query all accounts that scott owns, you will get his own, as well as the joint account, and same goes for ford. Maybe also add a flag to the account table to indicate whether the account is a joint account or not?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM account
WHERE cust_id = searchValue
```

If you were to enter scotts, or fords value, you would get 2.

Answer (score 0):

If Scott, c100, and Ford, c200, both have a joint account with the acc_id a300 then acc_id a300 should appear twice in the account table.

The account table should like this:

```
--------------------------
acc_id | cust_id
--------------------------
a300   | c100
a300   | c200
a100   | c100
a200   | c200
```

When you query using Scott's id you will only see two accounts because that is true, Scott has two accounts.

To see how many accounts each customer has you want to use this query:

```
select cust_id, count(acc_id) as num_accounts
from account
group by cust_id
```